# Spliting a string multiple times by a word?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Im making the switch from Visual Basic to c#. In my project i had it split a string a few times and one of them being by a word. Here was my VB code:

```
    Dim Item As String() = New String() {TXTItem1.Text + "-"}
        If Foods.Contains(TXTItem1.Text) Then
            Dim Substring As String = Foods.Split(Item, StringSplitOptions.None)(1)
            Dim SPValue As String = Substring.Split(vbNewLine)(0)
            MsgBox(SPValue)
```

Now here is my c# code:

```
     string[] Item = new string[] {TXTSearchItem.Text + "-"};
        if (Foods.Contains(TXTSearchItem.Text))
        {
            string Substring = Foods.Split(Item, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];

            MessageBox.Show(Substring);
```

For some reason i cannot split it again and the `MessageBox` isnt even showing. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: `string.Contains()` method is case sensitive, so I suppose the textbox does not contain the exact string stored in Foods.

Comment: The `MessageBox` shows now. I just cant seem to get it to split by a `Newline`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the Foods object? Is that an array or a String?

If I'm not mistaken, I believe that the Split extension method on a string would create an Array of type String instead of a String.

So that MessageBox.Show method may only be showing the String array as an object or not compiling correctly since Substring is declared as a String instead of an Array.

*Edit.

Would this be what you are looking for? This would only show the information that occurs after the Item String Array in the MessageBox.Show method.

```
    string[] Item = new string[] { TXTSearchItem.Text + "-" };
    if (Foods.ToLower().Contains(TXTSearchItem.Text.ToLower()))
    {
        string Substring = Foods.Split(Item, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];

        MessageBox.Show(Substring);
    }
```

Comment: So i wasn't paying attention and the reason the `MessageBox` wasn't showing was because it was case sensitive. I change it to be  `if (Foods.Contains(TXTSearchItem.Text.ToLower()))`. Now i just need to split it by  a `Newline` When i put ` string SPValue = Substring.Split(Environment.NewLine)[0];` it says cannot convert string to char. Foods is a string that is downloaded from a DropBox link.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The string would contain stuff like this for ex: `Bananna-0(newline)Eggs-0(newline)` ect. when the user enters eggs it will give back 0. I need to split it by a new line so it doesnt give back 0 and what ever is under that.

Comment: Just giving back the final result of 0 for example

Comment: So the messagebox would contain just the result of whatever the user typed in? Like if I type Banana, the message box should display "0"?

Comment: OK, I just edited my answer. From what I tested out, if you have a value of "Banana-0" in the TXTSearchItem.Text, the MessageBox will only show "0" so it looks like what you had was correct to display that!

Comment: Thanks! I input your code and it gave `0` but also gave anything below that in the string. That is why i need to split it by a `Newline`

Comment: Just got it! Here is my code.` string[] Item = new string[] { TXTSearchItem.Text.ToLower() + "-" };
            string[] Newline = new string[] {Environment.NewLine };
            if (Foods.ToLower().Contains(TXTSearchItem.Text.ToLower()))
            {
                string Substring = Foods.Split(Item, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
                string SPValue = Substring.Split(Newline, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
                MessageBox.Show(SPValue);
            }` Thanks for the help! Marked your answer as correct as most of it was! :)

Comment: That is great! I’m glad that you were able to get the answer good job!!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using string.Split, how about you just search for what you are looking for; it's probably simpler:

```
const string foods = "Banana-21\r\nEggs-123\r\n";
const string item = "banana";
var startIndex = foods.IndexOf(item + "-", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
var dashIndex = foods.IndexOf("-", startIndex);
var endIndex = foods.IndexOf("\r\n", startIndex);
var foodName = foods.Substring(startIndex, dashIndex - startIndex);
var footCount = foods.Substring(dashIndex + 1, endIndex - dashIndex - 1);
MessageBox.Show($"[{foodName}]:  {footCount}");
```

But, if you really want to use string.Split, here's an example (doing something similar):

```
const string foods = "Banana-21\r\nEggs-123\r\nCandy-1\r\n";
var foodItems = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var records = foods.Split(new[]{ "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var foodRecord in records)
{
    var parts = foodRecord.Split(new[] { "-" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (!int.TryParse(parts[1], out var foodCount))
    {
        foodCount = 0;
    }
    foodItems.Add(parts[0], foodCount);
}
```

After that code runs, you end up with foodItems containing:

```
[0]    {[Banana, 21]}
[1]    {[Eggs, 123]}
[2]    {[Candy, 1]}
```

For what it's worth, it makes a lot more sense (to me, at least) to split on the line ends first, then split each line (or just the line you are interested in).

Comment: I just tried this out and im having some trouble. The string foods is a streamreader which reads a txtfile from a dropbox link. Im not able to set foods because it is sr.readtoend() also the item is a textbox